# Doing damage inside a Ward of Dawn

Tags: destiny

The Titan Ward of Dawn protects everyone from shooting from outside of the shield and no one inside it can shoot out.
Though can I go inside an enemy Ward of Dawn and kill the players inside of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still take damage inside the bubble. The bubble only prevents damage from passing through it.

Comment: Note as well that it is a solid barrier to projectiles, so don't fire your rocket launcher in there!

Comment: or throw grenade

Comment: Some grenades don't hurt you I've noticed. Specifically the hunter lightning one that does the sweep-and-shock thing. Love being able to throw that at my feet!

Answer (score 0):

You can,but they ignore 90 percent of your damage in total,so just don't go in there unless you want to get punched to death. I have punched BLADEDANCERS to death in my sheild.